# GraphicOverlay class is't recognized by android studio compiler

Tags: java, android, ocr, google-vision, text-recognition

I have been work recently with Ocr for text recognition and tried to implement GraphicOverlay object, but it won't be recognized by the compiler.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
First you need to register your application details like name and package name on firebase console, after creating you can download google-services.json file, keep the file inside your app folder.

add below libraries on app build.gradle file
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0'

Go to Tools -> click on Firebase, please connect your project with firebase via Firebase Assistant. 

Try to clean and build project once. 

that's it.
```